# Angular reactive form issue with nested forms. How to declare in ts file and access the fields in html file

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I need a reactive form which when submitted should send json as following way.

```
"paymentData": {
    "paymentDetail": [
      {
        "amount": "string",
        "paymentMethod": "cash",
        "paymentReceiptNumber": "string",
        "paymentTxNumber": "string",
        "paymentType": "string"
      }
    ]
  }
```

I am trying to use a form array for my solution what unsuccessful so far.

```
 this.individualProcessingForm = this.formBuilder.group({
paymentData: this.formBuilder.array([this.createPaymentList()]),
  });

  createPaymentList(): FormGroup {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      paymentReceiptNumber: [''],
      amount: ['', [individualProcessingValidationService.invalidPaymentAmount]],
      paymentType: [''],
      paymentMethod: ['',[individualProcessingValidationService.paymentMethodValidation]],
      paymentTxNumber: [''],
    });
  }
```

In TS file I have method to get hold of paymentData form

```
 get paymentDataHandler() {

    return this.individualProcessingForm.controls.paymentData;
  }
```

Then in HTML file I am trying to access it like this.

```
    <div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="radiant-label radiant-h5">{{'label.payment.method' | translate}}</label>
            <mat-select class="form-control" name="paymentMethod" formControlName="paymentMethod"
              [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && paymentDataHandler.controls.paymentMethod.errors }">
              <mat-option value="">Select</mat-option>
              <mat-option *ngFor="let paymentMethod of paymentMethodTypes" [value]="paymentMethod">{{paymentMethod}}
              </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
            <app-generic-validation-msg *ngIf="submitted && paymentDataHandler"
              [control]="paymentDataHandler.controls.paymentMethod"></app-generic-validation-msg>
          </div>
        </div></div></div>
```

but above giving me errors like

> ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'paymentData -> paymentMethod'

Comment: Hi, did you solved this?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale Not yet. See my response below.

Comment: Are you sure this is the code that you have

Comment: @PrashantPimpale Yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer to initial question**

If you want the JSON you stated above, you have a wrap the form array inside another form group like this:

```
this.formGroup = this.fb.group({
    paymentData: this.fb.group({
        paymentDetail: this.fb.array([this.createPaymentList()])
    })
});
```

Have a look [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v9h45q)

**Answer to updated question**

Well I can't really see how the form of your data fits your view, so it is a bit hard trying to answer the question, but if you want to access a control from a formArray you need to do the following:

```
getFormArrayControl(index: number) {
   return this.formGroup.get('paymentData').get('paymentDetail').get(`${index}`) as FormGroup;
}
```

An element inside a FormArray is referenced by its index but not as a number but as a string.

Using this method you would be able to use `getControl` inside your template to access then elements inside the formGroup like `amount` or `paymentMethod`

eg.:

```
this.getFormArrayControl(0).get('paymentMethod') //inside the ts

{{getFormArrayControl(0).get('paymentMethod')}} //inside the template
```

Usually you would use a FormArray to iterate through that inside your template and then display the data inside it. For some reason you seem to have a different property there. I don't quite understand that sort of setting but in case you would want to iterate over your form array inside the template you could do something like this:

```
<div formArrayName="paymentDetail"
  *ngFor="let item of formGroup.get('paymentData').get('paymentDetail').controls; let i = index;">
  <div [formGroupName]="i">
    <input formControlName="amount">
  </div>
</div>
```

Have a look [at this article](https://alligator.io/angular/reactive-forms-formarray-dynamic-fields/). It describes the use of FormArrays quite well.

---

**Just a side note you might want to consider:**

If the data required by your backend looks quite different to the data structure you are trying to display to the user maybe it might be worth the effort to create your own view data structure and convert between those two. The code would become more readable and understandable.

Comment: Thanks Erbsenkoenig. Thats pretty much looks like the solution but I also need to access the  paymentData fields inside html form and for that I have done something like this ````get paymentDataHandler() {

    return this.individualProcessingForm.controls.paymentData;
  } ````  but this is giving errors like ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'paymentData -> paymentMethod'

Comment: Well you can access the paymentData fields, of course. What have you tried so far? Please update the question, or maybe even ask a new one since this question only asked for how to achieve a formGroup having the specific structure.

Comment: You are accessing a property from an array by chosing which element inside your array you want to access using the index as a string. So for example if you want the first element you would need to use ```this.formGroup.get('paymentData').get('paymentDetail).get('0')``` for the first element inside the form array located inside the paymentData formGroup and paymentDetail form group

Comment: Have a look here this is a good explanation about how to use the formArray inside the template https://alligator.io/angular/reactive-forms-formarray-dynamic-fields/

Comment: Thanks Erbsenkoenig .I have updated the question.Can you guide me to right direction here.

Comment: Tried the article approach but got  Error: Cannot find control with name: 'paymentDetail' and Error: Cannot find control with path: 'paymentDetail -> 0' .

Comment: Are we doing this right <div formArrayName="paymentDetail"> Reason I am asking is because paymentDetail is inside PaymentData. May be which is why it is not able to recognize paymentDetails. In example there is only on level down but we have here object contains another object which contains array object.